# Use $.extend with user defined object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, ecmascript-6

A library that i'm using (DataTables) accept a object declared with all customized options.

The code fail when the library try to build the result configuration with something like `$.extend({}, defaults , confs)` and receive a user defined object.
Unfortunately all the method defined in `confs` are missing in the result of `$.extend`

This code explain what am i trying to do:

```
class BaseConf {
    constructor() {
        this.ordering = false;
    }
    initComplete() {
        console.log('BaseConf.foo executed');
    }
}

class ExtendedConf extends BaseConf {
    initComplete() {
        super.foo();
        console.log('ExtendedConf.foo executed');
    }
}

conf = new ExtendedConf();


mergedConf = $.extend({}, conf);

console.log(mergedConf.ordering);     // <-- print false
console.log(mergedConf.initComplete); // <-- print undefined
```

Any idea of why this happen and some suggestion to how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end result of `$.extend` is a shallow copy of the object `conf` to the target object `{}`.

However, *it does not alter the prototype of the target object*. So while the instance properties are copied over from `conf` to `{}`, `{}` does not become an instance of either `ExtendedConf` or `BaseConf`, therefore does not carry the `initComplete` method.

What you could do is instead of just `{}`, you could use `Object.create` to create an object whose prototype is `ExtendedConf`'s prototype. That way, the resulting object inherits `ExtendedConf`. After which, use jQuery's `$.extend` to copy over the instance properties.

```
var conf = $.extend(Object.create(ExtendedConf.prototype), conf);
```

Comment: ok now i understand why my code fail, so the only solution would be change the code inside the library to avoid use of $.extend?